# column layout not displaying properly when display is set

Tags: html, css

CSS/HTML Beginner that is grateful for any help:
I have a table with the following CSS properties set for it:

```
.t5
{
    width: 1000px;
    column-width: 300px;
    column-width: 175px;
    column-width: 110px;
    column-width: 110px;
    column-width: 210px;
    column-width: 90px;
    }
```

As long as I don't enter any specific "display" attribute in html, it works perfectly. As soon as I choose "display:block", "display:table", "display: table-row" or even "display:initial", the output completely ignores my column width settings and minimizes them to the length of the text in each cell.

```
 <table class="t5";>
 <tr id="country1row1" style="display:block";>
     <td colspan="2">Product A</td>
     <td>Quantity Offered:</td>
     <td> <input id="volume1" type="text" value="0"  </td>
     <td>Sales Price Requested (in EURO):</td>
     <td> <input id="price1" type="text" value="0.00" </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you check your styles using the developer tools by pressing the f12 for example in chrome and look there what css has affecting your style

you can also try to be specific when styling like this

```html
<td style="width:100px">sample 1</td> <td style="width:200px">sample 2</td>
```

Comment: Thanks. That's probably the simplest way to solve it for now.